# Backbone localstorage, deleting a row by a field

Tags: backbone.js, local-storage

I'm using the localstorage adapter by jeromegn https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage..

I am wondering if there's any way to delete an item with in local storage by a where clause, using his adapter..

Within my collection I have

```
localStorage: new Store("stuff")
```

And then within a separate view, I need something like this..

`Collection.destroy({name = "Danny"});` - Which will find the row with danny and delete it..

Do I need to change his destroy function?

```
destroy: function(model) {
    this.localStorage().removeItem(this.name+"-"+model.id);
    this.records = _.reject(this.records, function(record_id){return record_id == model.id.toString();});
    this.save();
    return model;
  }
```

How can I go about doing this, cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
var name = "Danny";

var _name = Collection.find( function( model ) {
     return model.get("Name") === name;
});

_name.destroy();
```